# SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED in Sftp even the directory has 777 perms

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, filesystems, sftp

I have an **sftp** server with a directory located into

```
/share/data
```

This directory belongs to the `root` user so I've granted all permission to the dir:

```
chmod -R 777 /share
```

But if I try to create a new directory inside `/share/data/mynewdir` via SFTP client with a different user the SFTP server reply `SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED`

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: This error may happen when using rclone, but I don't know the solution yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe change the owner of the /newdir folder by doing a chown -R  user:group 
 /share/data/newdir

chown --help

chmod --help

https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchown.htm

Comment: Do you have any reference for your claim that a directory that belongs to root cannot be used by no one else?

Comment: no actually I have no problem with that besides I use winscp that I love but I gave a direction but I misspoke it being French and translating everything with deepl.com
HS: Thanks for your great work on winscp